# Question about the Fundamental group of circle.

Tags: algebraic-topology

We were taught in class that $\pi(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$

I am a bit confused as to why this is true. The motivation behind this was that if we have $\alpha_1$ moving around the circle once in a clockwise direction, and $\alpha_3$ moving around three times then $\alpha_1 \cdot \alpha_3=\alpha_4$.

My question is why is $\alpha_1$ not homotopic to $\alpha_3$?

It seems a that if we just moved around the cirlce at $\frac{1}{3}$ the speed we could easily "deform" $\alpha_3$ in to $\alpha_1$.

Comment: The homotopies in the definition of the fundamental group need to respect basepoints; in other words, you always need to be starting and stopping at the basepoint at every step. If you try this "slow down how fast I'm moving" homotopy you'll find that in the middle you won't end up at the basepoint anymore, and that's not allowed by the definition.

Comment: Qiaochu is correct. Imagine your loop $\alpha_{1}$ is a string with both ends nailed to a table (one nail: both ends are in the same spot). Now imagine that $\alpha_{3}$ is a string which is looped around itself 3 times, then its endpoints are nailed. No matter how you move or stretch the first string you will not be able to make it look like the second. This is precisely because you are not allowed to move the endpoints.